# Solution of general Dirichlet problem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space, $\kappa$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$ and $X_I$ denote the projection from $E^{\mathbb N_0}$ onto $E^I$ for $I\subseteq\mathbb N_0$.

We know that for every probability measure $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$, there is a unique probability $\operatorname P_\mu$ on $(E^{\mathbb N_0},\mathcal E^{\otimes\mathbb N_0})$ with $$\forall n\in\mathbb N_0:\operatorname P_\mu\circ X_{\{0,\:\ldots\:,\:n\}}=\mu\otimes\kappa^{\otimes n}\tag1.$$

Let $\operatorname P_x:=\operatorname P_{\delta_x}$ for $x\in E$ and $\operatorname E_\mu$ denote the expectation with respect to $\operatorname P_x$.

Let $X_n:=X_{\{n\}}$ for $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and $$\theta_k:E^{\mathbb N_0}\to E^{\mathbb N_0}\;,\;\;\;\omega\mapsto(\omega_{k+n})_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$$ for $k\in\mathbb N_0$. We know that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is a strong Markov process on $(E^{\mathbb N_0},\mathcal E^{\otimes\mathbb N_0},\operatorname P_\mu)$ for every probability measure $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$; i.e. $$\operatorname E_\mu\left[f\circ\theta_\tau\mid\mathcal F_\tau\right]=\operatorname E_{X_\tau}[f]\tag2$$ for every finite stopping time $\tau$ and all bounded and $\mathcal E^{\otimes I}$-measurable $f:E^I\to\mathbb R$. In particular, if $g:E\to\mathbb R$ is bounded and $\mathcal E$-measurable and $n\in\mathbb N_0$, then $$\operatorname E_\mu\left[g(X_{\tau+n})\mid\mathcal F_\tau\right]=(\kappa^{\otimes n}g)(X_\tau)\tag3.$$

**Question**: How do we obtain the second equality in the first equation of the proof in [Proposition 4.4.2 of *Markov Chains* by Randal Douc, Eric Moulines, Pierre Priouret, Philippe Soulier](https://books.google.de/books?id=QaZ-DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=%22In+words,+we+are+looking+for+a+function+that+is+harmonic%22&source=bl&ots=YHIAi5QH8d&sig=ACfU3U1XK8pnxYLodeS14REVa6f3YV52_Q&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22In%20words%2C%20we%20are%20looking%20for%20a%20function%20that%20is%20harmonic%22&f=false)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You’re writing the inner conditional expectation as a “regular”expectation with a shift operator. See proposition 3.4.3 of [Meyn and Tweedie](http://probability.ca/MT/BOOK.pdf). This is the (weak) Markov property. Then, you remove one of the extra expectation operators.

Edit: more details:

Your definition (4.4.3) gives you
$$
P_A g(x) = \mathbb{E}_x\left[ \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau_A < \infty\} }g(X_{\tau_A}) \right]
$$
Thinking of this as a random variable:
$$
P_A g(X_1)  = \mathbb{E}_{X_1}\left[ \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau_A < \infty\} }g(X_{\tau_A}) \right] . 
$$

Then using the weak Markov property:
$$
P_A g(X_1)  = \mathbb{E}_{x}\left[ \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau_A < \infty\} }g(X_{\tau_A}) \circ \theta \mid \mathcal{F}_1 \right] . 
$$
You're using the weak Markov property because the time shift is deterministic.

Last, when you reintroduce the outer expectation, it's the law of total expectation.